# What is the underlying hard problem in the reduction of game-based proofs?

Tags: provable-security, random-oracle-model

I am confused by how game-based proofs fit in the provable security paradigm. I understand reductions in the style of proving secrecy of RSA reducing it to integer factorization. However, when proving indistinguishability properties with game-based proofs, I cannot identify the underlying hard mathematical problem of the reduction.

Comment: Aren't game based proof a method of establishing that a problem reduces to a hard problem, rather than a hard problem by itself? Wouldn't it depend therefore on the problem being analyzed?

Comment: Yes, you're right: they are a method to find a reduction. So, I guess I'm looking for examples of hard problems to which a game-based proof shows a reduction for.